# ASM : Trouble using int21h on real machine

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I want to input a char in ASM compare it to a defined char and print a message if they are the same or retry if they aren't

Problem is that my code works on emu8086 but not on a VM:

```
mdp DB 'c$'
equal : 

       mov ah, 1h
       int 21h

cmp al,mdp
jne equal
```

On emu8086 it wait user to press a key and to press enter, on a VM (as a bootloader) I can't press any key.

Comment: Ask the original author (i.e. Sebatian Plotz himself)

Comment: `int 21h` is part of the DOS API (also implemented in Windows). You can't use it in a bootloader where the OS hasn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use MS-DOS services (INT 21h) in a bootloader. MS-DOS is an operating system, like Linux or Windows. Just like how you can't use Linux services before Linux has loaded, you can't use MS-DOS services before it has loaded.

In a bootloader you're restricted to using BIOS services (or accessing the hardware directly). You can use the BIOS service INT 16h, AH=00h to read the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks i discovered it 5 minutes ago ahah.
My problem is solved thanks you !